# Откуда классу с внедрённой зависимостью через интерфейс известно о классе, с которым реально надо работать?

Tags: java, ооп

Столкнулся с проблемой понимания внедрения зависимостей.

Допустим, есть интерфейс `TaxCalculator` с методом `double calculateTax()`. Данный метод реализуется классом `TaxCalculator2018`.

Внедрение зависимости осуществляется через конструктор класса TaxReport. В классе есть приватная переменная private `TaxCalculator calculator` (переменная с типом интерфейса). Переменную с таким же типом принимает конструктор - `public TaxReport(TaxCalculator calculator){...}`

Наконец, в основном классе есть такой код.

```
TaxCalculator2018 calculator = new TaxCalculator2018(100_000);
TaxReport report = new TaxReport(calculator);
```

В конечном итоге в calculator попадает ссылка на объект `TaxCalculator2018`, после чего отправляется в конструктор класса `TaxReport`. Между тем, конструктор класса `TaxReport` должен принимать объект с типом `TaxCalculator`, то есть интерфейс.

Как так получается, что класс с внедрённой зависимостью через интерфейс понимает, что надо работать не с интерфейсом, а объектом `TaxCalculator2018`, который этот самый интерфейс реализует? Что это за механизм? Нет ли подробной статьи с объяснением?

Comment: Ну это так работает полиморфизм) Мы ждем в `TaxReport` любой класс, реализующий интерфейс `TaxCalculator`

Comment: если у вас есть интерфейс и его реализует всего один класс, то несложно догадаться, какой именно инстанс будет использован. если классов, имплементирующих интерфейс 2 и более, то вам нужно будет дополнительно определять механизм выбора между этими классами. так или иначе любой IOC и DI(как его часть)работает на рафлексии

Comment: Выходит в методе public TaxReport(TaxCalculator calculator) {...} на человеческом языке параметр TaxCalculator calculator означает, как написали выше, любой класс, который реализует интерфейс TaxCalculator?

Comment: Прочитайте про [binding](http://pr0java.blogspot.com/2015/07/blog-post_66.html)
или
посмотрите [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDpns6k9-iU)

Answer (score 1):

> Как так получается, что класс с внедрённой зависимостью через интерфейс понимает, что надо работать не с интерфейсом, а объектом TaxCalculator2018, который этот самый интерфейс реализует?

никак не понимает (можно конечно явно преобразовать), в этом нет необходимости, вместо `TaxCalculator2018` там может оказаться любой другой класс реализующий интерфейс.

> Что это за механизм?

механизм [Извлечение интерфейса](https://refactoring.guru/ru/extract-interface)